# how to put case condition in my Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query in stored procedure.

In the above query I have @UpdateBy Field there I need to check if the @Updateby filed is NULL or Empty I need to get AddedBy filed. how do I need to Update my Query for that case?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You might want to restore at least a little bit of the stored procedure code, otherwise the question/answer won't make much sense to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `(CASE WHEN Isnull(@UpdateBy,'') = '' THEN @AddedBy ELSE @UpdateBy END)`.

Edit:  The above is the general idea.  Here's what it might look like within the select of the stored procedure.  (Don't forget to do it twice, because of the UNION):

```
...
    ,Current_record.value('inserted[1]/@Status','VARCHAR(10)') AS Status
    ,(CASE
        WHEN Isnull(Current_record.value('inserted[1]/@UpdatedBy','VARCHAR(100)'),'' ) = '' THEN Current_record.value('inserted[1]/@AddedBy','VARCHAR(100)')
        ELSE Current_record.value('inserted[1]/@UpdatedBy','VARCHAR(100)')
        END
    ) as UpdatedBy,
    ,CAST(Current_record.value('inserted[1]/@BaVariableId','VARCHAR(100)') AS INT) AS VariableId
...
```

Comment: Thank you Dwright, where Do i need to put this thing in my SP exactly, Sorry I am new to this SP.

Comment: Can you post the full stored procedure?  It will make it easier to answer where you need to put the case statement.

Comment: See my edit above.  Hope this helps.  This is assuming that current_record really has an @AddedBy?

Comment: What kind of trigger is this coming off of?

Comment: Yes Current record will have AddedBy